# I am getting error while filtering using rest api on firebase

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database with user information in firebase. I want to filter the person whose email address is afenerli@gmail.com using Rest. For this, I wrote a rest url as follows.

> [https://afenerli-1de3e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy='email'&equalTo='afenerli@gmail.com'](https://afenerli-1de3e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy=%27email%27&equalTo=%27afenerli@gmail.com%27)

I'm getting a bad request error. Why ?

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error? Did you add the [index in your rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-value)?

Comment: The query looks good at first glance. Do you have any more specific details in the error response? If no, can you post your JSON as text, so I can try to reproduce it? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.